# Android App and Windows Azure Mobile Services

Tags: android, azure-mobile-services

I have a simple android program similar to the ToDoActivity from Windows Azure Mobile Services and whenever I get an incoming call the app throws an exception once the call ends but does not close the program. Can anyone give me any information on how to stop this?

Heres what logcat is throwing:

```
10-02 12:32:17.682: W/System.err(6314): com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceException: Error while processing request.
10-02 12:32:17.757: W/System.err(6314):     at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceConnection$1.onNext(MobileServiceConnection.java:122)
10-02 12:32:17.757: W/System.err(6314):     at com.creative.connection.timeschedulr.DisplayContentActivity$ProgressFilter.handleRequest(DisplayContentActivity.java:819)
10-02 12:32:17.757: W/System.err(6314):     at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceConnection.start(MobileServiceConnection.java:93)
10-02 12:32:17.757: W/System.err(6314):     at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.RequestAsyncTask.doInBackground(RequestAsyncTask.java:77)
10-02 12:32:17.757: W/System.err(6314):     at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.RequestAsyncTask.doInBackground(RequestAsyncTask.java:1)
10-02 12:32:17.757: W/System.err(6314):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
10-02 12:32:17.757: W/System.err(6314):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
10-02 12:32:17.757: W/System.err(6314):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
10-02 12:32:17.757: W/System.err(6314):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
10-02 12:32:17.757: W/System.err(6314):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
10-02 12:32:17.757: W/System.err(6314):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
10-02 12:32:17.757: W/System.err(6314): Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: scheduler.azure-mobile.net
10-02 12:32:17.768: W/System.err(6314):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:516)
10-02 12:32:17.768: W/System.err(6314):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
10-02 12:32:17.768: W/System.err(6314):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
10-02 12:32:17.768: W/System.err(6314):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
10-02 12:32:17.768: W/System.err(6314):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
10-02 12:32:17.768: W/System.err(6314):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
10-02 12:32:17.768: W/System.err(6314):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
10-02 12:32:17.768: W/System.err(6314):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
10-02 12:32:17.768: W/System.err(6314):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
10-02 12:32:17.768: W/System.err(6314):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
10-02 12:32:17.768: W/System.err(6314):     at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.execute(AndroidHttpClient.java:243)
10-02 12:32:17.768: W/System.err(6314):     at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.ServiceFilterRequestImpl.execute(ServiceFilterRequestImpl.java:71)
10-02 12:32:17.772: W/System.err(6314):     at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceConnection$1.onNext(MobileServiceConnection.java:102)
10-02 12:32:17.772: W/System.err(6314):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: What is the call stack / error message from the exception?

Comment: What version of Android are you running where this is occurring?  This is on a device and not the emulator correct?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is being thrown because the app is, at the time, unable to reach your Mobile Service as noted by this:

Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: scheduler.azure-mobile.net

If you're able to reproduce this, I highly doubt it has to do with the Mobile Service or the SDK as opposed to network availability on your device.  Without being able to see from where inside of your application the error is being thrown (i.e. what is triggering the network request) it's difficult to say exactly what might be causing this.  My only hypothesis would be that somehow you're triggering the network request when the device still doesn't have any network connectivity due to the phone call.  If you could provide exact steps to reproduce and what is triggering the network request, I might be able to dig deeper.